# How to update value in FormArrays

Tags: angular

I have a formBuilder array and a need change his value.

i tried setvalue, but just change the visual.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpqyjw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
updateAddress(i,address) {
    // (<FormControl>this.form.controls['adresses'][i].controls.estado).setValue('RR');
    address.value.states = 'GOIAS'
  }

  initializeFormEmpty() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      adresses: this.formBuilder.array([this.addressItem()])
    })
  }
  addressItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      zip_code: this.formBuilder.control('', [Validators.required]),
      states: this.formBuilder.control('RORAIMA', [Validators.required]),
    })
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpqyjw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `updateAddress` function to the following:

```js
  updateAddress(i,address) {
    let myFormArray = this.form.get('adresses') as FormArray;
    myFormArray.controls[i].get('states').setValue('GOIAS');
  }
```

Here's a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7prt4s?file=src/app/app.component.ts) of what I believe you are trying to accomplish.